# Does a class have a (unique) identity in Java?

Tags: java, class, identity

Is the statement "*A class has a unique identity*." true or false?

Objects in java have their unique identity (at least by their memory address) but does a class have one too? Since a class is not an object I'm confused about this. Or does a class need to be instantiated (is that even possible)?

Comment: .......................true

Comment: A class needs to be instantiated (will be done if you do `import` or `Class.forName()` or `ClassLoader#loadClass()` or something like that

Comment: If a Class didn't have a unique identity, then it would be impossible to instantiate a defined instance of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both true and false, depending on your definition of identity.

Because classes are located and loaded into the JVM by their fully qualified name (FQN), e.g. `java.lang.String`, it's tempting to think of these FQNs as unique, but the Java program can have multiple `ClassLoader` instances running, each with their own versions of classes loaded that share the same FQN. These classes and their instances would fail an equality check in the code, and could not be cast to one another, even if they're loaded from the same `.class` file on disk.

So the statement is false in that there can be multiple classes loaded with the same identity, but the statement is true in that they're all uniquely distinguishable in the eyes of the JVM.

Answer (score 4):

Each class has an associated instance (`Object.class` for the `Object` class). This instance is unique *per class loader*. This means that class do have a unique identity inside a class loader. However, the same `Foo` class can be loaded twice in a JVM, eg in two different webapps of a container.

Note also that « system classes » are always loaded by the root class loader, and thus have a unique identity across a JVM.

Answer (score 0):

First a class must be unique at the package level but you can have the same class name in different packages.  Consider `java.util.Timer` and `java.swing.Timer`.  There are many other examples.

And not all classes need to be instantiated to be used.  Consider the `Math` class which has static methods.

Comment: The name itself does not make a class unique. Several versions of a class can be loaded through different class loaders.

Comment: My statement does not imply that it does.

Comment: To me, you're implying that class `x.y.z.Example` is unique by virtue of its name alone, and that may be true in simple Java applications, but with multiple class loader hierarchies, you can load multiple distinct variants of `x.y.z.Example`.

Answer (score -1):

Its name is its unique identifier if you include to it the package it is placed in.

Comment: That is not necessarily true. With multiple class loader hierarchies, a class may be loaded twice into the same JVM, both classes will have the same name, but they will have separate identities (and they may or may not have different bytecode, eg if different versions were loaded).

Comment: To back up Mark with an anecdote: For a college project we ran a Wildfly server with four deployments, three of which contained the same class in the same package. That eventually gave us ClassCastExceptions from seemingly one class to the same (think `com.example.Film` to `com.example.Film`) but from different deployments. Only when we ran each deployment on its own Wildfly using Docker we were able to get around this issue. The same thing happened when a dependency included a different version of a library that was already present on the server. So I think this answer might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks ! That's interesting! Makes me think that I should make a few changes to some of my code.